# Private Key Sharding - How is it Secure in a Distributed Network?

Tags: encryption, hash, public-key, secret-sharing

In a Distributed Network in order for a private key not to be compromised sharding will have to take place off the network, correct?

If so: Why is it when a Distributed Network shards private keys that they are so worried about it being comprised in the network when the sharded keys are encrypted? Does decryption take place in the Network? If so: Why can decryption not be done off the network?